# SHA-256. Is it possible to split the workload of this hashing algorithm between multiple computers?

Tags: hash, cryptography, sha256, bitcoin

This is a question that has been on my mind for quite some time now. Is it actually possible to split the workload of the SHA-256 between two or more computers which are working in parallel with each other? If so, are there any examples you can show me? Your opinions are welcome.  Please tell me if you think such a system would be beneficial or if you think it would be inefficient.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) or [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot split SHA-256 calculations - or any other SHA-1, 2 or 3 algorithm - as each *block* is dependent on the previous block. You cannot even speed up verification as you don't store the blocks that are calculated in between. Actually, [there are no known hashes where this can be done without some kind of number theoretic construction which would significantly slow down the hash](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1558/1172).

What you can however do is to use a [hash- or Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree). Such a tree consists of hash values that in turn can be hashed to form another node (ad-infinitum). At the very least the leaf nodes can be calculated in parallel.